# Question about inverse of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, block-matrices

> Consider the block upper triangular matrix
> $$A = \left[ \begin{matrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ 0 & A_{22} \end{matrix} \right], $$
> where $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $A_{11}\in\mathbb R^{k\times k}$ with $1 \le k \le n$. Suppose $A_{12} \ne 0$ and that we want to block diagonlize $A$ via the similartiy transformation
> $$T = \left[ \begin{matrix} I & X \\ 0 & I \end{matrix} \right], $$ where $X\in\mathbb R^{k\times (n-k)}$, i.e.,
> $$ T^{-1}AT = \left[ \begin{matrix} A_{11} &0 \\ 0 & A_{22} \end{matrix} \right]. $$ Find a matrix equation $X$ must satisfy for this to be possible.

**Important**: my question is not how to solve the problem. I have question regarding finding $T^{-1}$.

The solution presented said that
$$T^{-1} = \left[ \begin{matrix} I & -X \\ 0 & I \end{matrix} \right]\label{eq:star} \tag{$\star$}.$$
Quesutions:

- Is $\eqref{eq:star}$ true?
- Why is it true?

Explanations are great! Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. Are you familiar with [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication)? If so, then you can check that this formula works by computing the product
$$
\pmatrix{I & X\\0 & I}\pmatrix{I & -X\\0 & I} = \pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & I}.
$$

Comment: I am familiar up to the idea of partitioning the matrix into blocks and matrix multiplication works only if the blocks are of "compatible sizes". I def should have checked that condition first... If you want to put that as an answer to the question I can accept it :) Thanks @BenGrossmann!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes. For the second question, you can check that this formula works by using [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) to compute the product
$$
\pmatrix{I & X\\0 & I}\pmatrix{I & -X\\0 & I} = \pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & I}.
$$

Comment: This works only if $I, X,$ and the other $I$ are of suitable sizes.

Comment: @markvs in this context, $I$ is an identity matrix. That is all that we need.

Comment: There are identity matrices of various sizes, so the two $I$'s are not equal in general.

Comment: @markvs The formula still works if the $I$'s have distinct sizes